# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - Is there any way I can solve that without increasing memory?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```java
public static void main (String[]args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> x= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0;i<Integer.MAX_VALUE;i++) {
        x.add(i);
    }

}
```

Why I am running out of memory? Is there any way I can store a lot of values into a list like for example from Integer.Min_value to Integer.Max_value?

Comment: Don't try to load all numbers at once and try to process to them in chunks like 5000 numbers in each attempt until you reach Integer.max_value. you can refer this link to see how to process in chunks- https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/10/how-to-read-large-file-in-java.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume you're using a 64-bit system, because a 32-bit system can't address more than 4 GiB of memory, which is not enough for your purpose.

Integer.MAX_VALUE is 2^31 - 1, or about 2 billion. An Integer object uses [24 bytes](https://ordepdev.me/posts/size-of-an-object-in-java) of memory, and an ArrayList with 2 billion elements must store references to those elements in at least an array of length 2 billion; each reference takes up 8 bytes.

So the total amount of memory you want to use is over 2 billion times 24 bytes, plus 2 billion times 8 bytes, which comes out at 64 GiB. If you have 128 GiB of memory, and you decide to let Java use all of it for some reason, then in theory this could be possible.

But **just don't do it**. There is no reason you would ever need an ArrayList containing all the integers from 0 to Integer.MAX_VALUE, except perhaps to win a bet. If you need to loop over the integers from 0 to Integer.MAX_VALUE, use a `for` loop like the one you have written; they don't need to all be in memory at once.

Comment: As a side-note, the length of an array (and hence, an ArrayList) in Java is limited to Integer.MAX_VALUE itself; so even if you have enough memory, you would only be able to fit the numbers from 0 to Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1. You certainly wouldn't be able to have a single ArrayList with all the integers from Integer.MIN_VALUE to Integer.MAX_VALUE.